# xamarin forms: Issue with creating IPA file

Tags: xamarin.ios, ipa

I follow the below steps for creating an IPA file.

- Selected the iOS project as the startup project.
- Select the Release | Device configuration in Visual Studio for Mac.
- From the Build menu, select Archive for Publishing.

At this 3rd stage, I am getting a pop-up box and telling "Configuration doesn't target device". I am adding the screenshot of the popup.

[image]

At the Debug mode device is there but when I changed it to the release mode it is showing the device as Default.
I refer the following blog; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=vsmac

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by following way.

Options from master project --> configurations -->check the build option of ios project.

[image]

Then the release mode showing the generic device option.

[image]